# 0..1 to 0..1 relationship in EF6 using database first

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to achieve the following scenario (note: I can make it work several ways in the database to get the desired behavior; I just can't make EF happy about it).

Our customers mount widgets onto dongles.  Sometimes, they screw up and have to remove the widget from the dongle; other times, they received a dongle with a broken widget, and they need to remove it.  We store the records of each mount and demount.

Conceptually, I have a Mount entity and a Demount entity.  A Mount may have an associated Demount, but it doesn't have to.  Similarly, a Demount may be tied to a previous mount, but it isn't always.  There is not really a need to start at a Demount and trace back to its original Mount, only from Mount to Demount.  We use GUIDs for everything, so my original design was to have the MountId column in the Demount table be nullable and have a foreign key to the Mount table's Id column; then, to make sure that a single Mount didn't get more than one Demount, I added a unique key constraint to the MountId column in the Demount table.  SQLServer understood what I wanted, and all was well in the world.  Entity Framework, however, insisted that I must have a (*) multiplicity on the Demount end of the relationship.

Next, I did the same thing only in reverse, adding a DemountId column to my MountData table, adding the same FKs and UKs, but now Entity Framework thinks I have two (0..1)-(*) associations, one going each direction.

Finally, I added a MountTies table with two columns (MountId, DemountId), a PK that uses both columns, a foreign key from each column to its respective entity table, and a UK on each column to ensure that I don't get two records for either entity.  Now, EF threw a fit saying 'At least one of the key properties of AssociationSet MountTies must be mapped to all the key properties of the table MountTies.

I think that adding back the nullable MountId and DemountId columns in the entity tables might fix this, but at this point, I'm too frustrated to undo changes, drop and recreate the database, redo the tables, etc. just to find out it won't work.  On top of that, I really don't want to have to add 3 extra GUID columns when the database is happy to work with just the one.  I believe the problem is in getting EF to recognize the UK constraints, so my question/s is/are: Is that the problem, and if so, how can I fix it without adding 1 extra table and 3 extra columns to my schema?

Comment: What you've designed is a Many to Many relationship, regardless of how you use it.

Comment: @ErikPhilips is right - this is a many-to-many relationship. To maintain your business rules, you can add unique keys to each of the columns in the many-to-many table.

Comment: @João Lourenço, I have the unique keys in place in each scenario I've tried so that each Mount can have no more than 1 Demount and each Demount can have no more than 1 Mount.  My problem is that Entity Framework doesn't seem to recognize the unique key constraints and insists on treating each entity's property as a collection of the other instead of a single one.